# Modify enum via constructor

Tags: c#

In my app I'm currently dealing with following problem. In Program class I define TradeType enum. I pass it via constructor to ExecutionClass. This class will do some work and will modify this enum. I would like to print out the modified this modified enum in my Program class after the work is done. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TradeType tradeType = new TradeType();

        ExecutionClass ex = new ExecutionClass(ref tradeType);
        
        ex.Run();// here the output is BUY, but I would like SELL to be returned
        
        Console.WriteLine(tradeType);
        
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
public class ExecutionClass
{
    private TradeType TradeType { get; set; }

    public ExecutionClass(ref TradeType someValue)
    {
        TradeType = someValue;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        TradeType = TradeType.SELL;
    }
}

public enum TradeType
{
    BUY,
    SELL
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(ex.TradeType)`?. The `ref` only passes the reference into the constructor: you can't have a `ref` field, and so the `TradeType` which you passed into the constructor is *copied* into the `TradeType` property.

Comment: Sure, in `public ExecutionClass()` you could do, say, `someValue = TraceType.SELL;` - that would be reflected in the caller due to `ref`.

Comment: No, it's not possible without using unsafe code (which you should avoid unless you have a really good reason).

Comment: C# does not have pointers. Therefore as a first step and without thinking or looking for a solution, you cannot do this in managed code. Unless you change the design and use a technique using delegates other than what you hope to work and which is based on the notion of C pointers. C # is not C, sorry. In reality the question is what do you want to do for a real application: what is your goal? What behavior do you need? Such a conCeptual question about C # is irrelevant, in my opinion.

Comment: @Olivier "C# does not have pointers" - uh?

Comment: @Llama In managed code, of course... and references are hidden pointers to forget to manage pointers 

Comment: An enum is a value type (it is based on `int` unless otherwise specified). Don't use `new()`. Assign it an enum value instead `var tradeType = TradeType.SELL;`. Or Assign it the default value ` `TradeType tradeType = default;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to wrap your enum in a class, and pass an instance into your constructor - which is a reference - and then any changes within the class will be reflected outside

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TradeTypeWrapper tradeType = new TradeTypeWrapper(TradeType.BUY);

        ExecutionClass ex = new ExecutionClass(tradeType);
        
        ex.Run();
        
        Console.WriteLine(tradeType.Value); // will output SELL
        
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

public class ExecutionClass
{
  private TradeTypeWrapper tradeType{ get; set; }

  public ExecutionClass(TradeTypeWrapper someValue) // no need for ref - class instances are references
  {
    tradeType = someValue;
  }

  public void Run()
  {
    tradeType.Value = TradeType.SELL;
  }
}

public class TradeTypeWrapper
{
    public TradeTypeWrapper(TradeType initialValue)
    {
        Value = initialValue;
    }
    public TradeType Value { get; set; }
}

public enum TradeType
{
    BUY,
    SELL
}
```

Another option is to pass the enum value by `ref` into the `Run` method itself, this does away with the need for a wrapper class, and might suit you better.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         ExecutionClass ex = new ExecutionClass();
        
        var tradeType = TradeType.BUY;
        ex.Run(ref tradeType);
        
        Console.WriteLine(tradeType); // will output SELL
    }
}


public class ExecutionClass
{
    public ExecutionClass()
    {
    }

    public void Run(ref TradeType someValue)
    {
        someValue = TradeType.SELL;
    }
}

public enum TradeType
{
    BUY,
    SELL
}
```

Last option is to just pass into your class the `TradeType` enum (as you have, but without `ref`) and have `Run` return the updated value of `TradeType` as appropriate

Comment: Using wrapper seems to be the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @xcelm It's how I would do it - however I was just musing another option of passing by ref into the `Run` method itself if that would suit you better (wouldnt require the wrapper). See update if you fancy that one instead.